# Android increment database value by one

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a method which should upgrade the unreadMessageCount of a given user.

```
public void increaseUnreadMessageCount(int userID) {
    String query = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT + " = "
            + DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT + " + 1 WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_USER_ID
            + " = ?";
    Log.i("query", query);
    db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { String.valueOf(userID) });
}
```

This evaluates to: `UPDATE user SET unreadPrivateMessageCount = unreadPrivateMessageCount + 1 WHERE userID = ?` which seems correct to me.
But somehow it is not working, the row is always 0.

Or is my SELECT statement wrong?

```
public int getUnreadPrivateMessageCount() {
    String query = "SELECT SUM(" + DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT + ") AS messageCount FROM "
            + tableName + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT + " <> ?";
    Log.i("query", query);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { "0" });
    int messageCount = 0;
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            messageCount = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("messageCount"));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            Log.e("getUnreadPrivateMessageCount", "moveToFirst failed");
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("getUnreadPrivateMessageCount", "count 0");
    }

    return messageCount;
}
```

This query evaluates to `SELECT SUM(unreadPrivateMessageCount) AS messageCount FROM user WHERE unreadPrivateMessageCount <> ?` and no error log is triggered, which also seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rawQuery` is used to execute *queries*, i.e., SELECT statements.
To execute other SQL statements, use `execSQL` instead.

Also check if you really want to treat your IDs as strings.

Comment: Doc of `execSQL` : "Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. "

Comment: @Chris The documentation is wrong; this function is not *intended* to execute those commands because there is no returned cursor (for SELECT) or there already are specialized functions (for the others).

Comment: Thanks, seems to work now. What's the purpose of life when the documentation is wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

If your update syntax is correct then :

```
public void increaseUnreadMessageCount(int userID) {
    String query = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT + " = "
            + DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT + " + 1 WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_USER_ID
            + " = ?";
    Log.i("query", query);
    db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { String.valueOf(userID) });
}
```

where did you use : `getUnreadPrivateMessageCount()`, no where, so it must be something like this :

```
public void increaseUnreadMessageCount(int userID) {
    String query = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT + " = "
            + getUnreadPrivateMessageCount() + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_USER_ID
            + " = ?";
    Log.i("query", query);
    db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { String.valueOf(userID) });
}
```

In this way total unread message is passed to table.

Comment: The method is obviously called in another place.